# Let $U,W$ be different subspaces of $\Bbb R^3$ such that $U \cap W \not= \{0\}$ and $U,W \not = \Bbb R^3$ which statement is true?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

> Let $U,W$ be different subspaces of $\Bbb R^3$ such that $U \cap W \not= \{0\}$  and $U,W \not = \Bbb R^3$ then:
>
> 1. $U+W= \Bbb R^3$
>
> 2.$dim(U \cap W)=1$ (according to the textbook this is the correct answer)
>
> 3. $U\subseteq W$ or $W \subseteq U$

---

The correct answer is statement $2$ but I am trying to prove why it is correct and why the others are not

**First statement -** since $\Bbb R^3$ is a finite dimension and $U \not= W \subseteq \Bbb R^3$ we get that $dim(U) \not = dim(V)$ and  $dim(U) \not = dim(V)$ so $dim(U)=0,1,2$ and $dim(W)=0,1,2$ as well , and from the given information $U \cap W \not= \{0\}$ they cannot be $0$ . I used a counter example, let $U=\{(1,0,0),(0,2,0)\}$ and $W=\{(1,0,0)\}$ from here we can get the spans so $Sp(W)=\{(1,0,0)\}$ and $Sp(U)= \{(1,0,0),(0,2,0)\}$ since they are linearly independent sets and we know that if the ets are not empty then $U+W=Sp(U)+Sp(W)=Sp(U \cup W)$ so $Sp(U \cup W)$ $=$ $\{(1,0,0),(0,2,0)\} \not= \Bbb R^3$

**Second statement -** I belive that it has to be related to this dimension theorem $dim(U+W)=dim(U)+dim(W)-dim(U \cap W)$ I think that $dim(U+W)$ can be at most $3$ so $3 \geq dim(U)+dim(W)-dim(U \cap W)$ but I don't know how to continue

**Third statement -** I read those two statements in the textbook , 1. $U+W=U$ $\iff$ $W \subseteq U$ and $\qquad$ 2. $U \cup W =U+W$ $\iff$ $U \subseteq W$ or $W \subseteq U$ and according to $1$ we get that $W=U$ but the question says that they are different

I would like to know if my approach and understanding is correct and how to actually prove the correct answer? (statement 2)

thanks for any tips and help , sorry if the translations to English are not correct hope it is understandable

Comment: If $\dim(U\cap V)\neq 1$, you have that $\dim(U\cap V)=2$, and thus $U=V$ which contradict $U\neq V$.

Comment: $U$ must have dimension 1 or 2, likewise $W$. If either one has dimension 1, then clearly the intersection has dimension 1. So you just have to think about the case where both have dimension 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First statement:** Yes, providing a counter example is enough and yours is correct.

**Second statement:** Since $\dim U,\dim V<3$, $\dim(U\cap W)\leqslant 2$. And, since $U\cap W\ne\{0\}$, $\dim(U\cap W)\geqslant 1$. So, if we did not have $\dim(U\cap W)=1$, then that dimension would have to be equal to $2$. But $U\cap W\subset U$ and therefore $\dim(U\cap W)\leqslant\dim U\leqslant 2$. Therefore,$$\dim(U\cap W)=2\implies U\cap W=U\iff W\subset U.$$By the same argument, we have $U\subset W$. But then $U=W$, and we are assuming that $U\ne W$.

**Third statement:** As before, all you need is to provide a counterexample, such as$$U=\operatorname{span}(\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\})\quad\text{and}\quad W=\operatorname{span}(\{(1,0,0),(0,0,1)\}).$$Concerning your approach, it is indeed true that $U+W=U\iff W\subset U$, but do you have some reason to assume that $U+W=U$?

Comment: Thank you it is more understandable now , just to be clear on one thing please , assume $U,W$ are subspaces of $V$ and $dim(V)=n$ then $dim(U+W)$ is always at most $n$? so this is always true? $n \geq dim(U)+dim(W)-dim(U \cap W)$
thank you for the help

Comment: Yes, it is always true.